# Combinatorial Minimization Problem for sets of rational numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms

If we have the set

$\Bigg\{ \frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...,\frac{1}{k} \Bigg\}=:A$

for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$ (known). We pick some $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that we have

$\Bigg\{ \frac{a}{1},\frac{a}{2},...,\frac{a}{k} \Bigg\}=:B$

The problem is, how do we pick the number $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a \neq k$ optimally so that the non-duplicates in the first and the second set are minimized i.e. $B$ shares as many elements as possible with $A$. By duplicates I refer to instances such as $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{4}=\frac{4}{8}$ for example.

Comment: You first talk about **minimizing** duplicates, then **maximizing** the cardinality of the intersection. Those are opposite goals, as the duplicates of both sets make up the intersection. Minimizing seems easy (just choose a negative $a$, then the intersection is empty), so I assume you want maximize it. In that case, $a\neq 1$ makes sense, instead of the $a\neq k$ you mentioned. Can you edit/clarify what you mean?

Comment: My bad, I was trying to say that we need to minimize the number of elements in $B$ that are different from elements in $A$. I fixed it.

Comment: This is the same problem as with $A = \{ 1, \dots, k \}$, and it might be easier to visualize this way. Then probably $a = 2$ or $a = \frac 1 2$ are the best choices.

Answer (score 1):

Hugo Manet has the right idea in his comment. I'll assume that the condition $$a \neq k$$ is actually $$a \neq 1,$$ as $a=1$ is the obvious solution with maximal intersection of $A$ and $B$, because then $A$=$B$.

First, $A$ is a $k$-element set, and the same is true for $B$ if $a \neq 0$. $a=0$ means $A \cap B =\emptyset$, so $a=0$ will never be the sole optimal solution, so we can forget about $a=0$. Similiarly, if $a<0$, we get $A \cap B =\emptyset$, so we can restrict ourselves to $a > 0$.

Let's consider an element $\frac1i \in A$, with $1 \le i \le k$. It can be equal to at most one $\frac{a}j \in B, 1 \le j \le k$. Similiarly, each $\frac{a}j \in B, 1 \le j \le k$ can b equal to at most one $\frac1i \in A$.

That means the cardinality of $A \cap B$ is the cardinality of

$$C_a=\{(i,j) \in \mathbb N^2, 1 \le i,j \le k \mid  \frac1i=\frac{a}j\} = \{(i,j) \in \mathbb N^2, 1 \le i,j \le k \mid  a =\frac{j}i\}.$$

Obviously, for each $i$ in the given range there can only be at most one $j$ in that range that fulfilles the qotient condition, and vice versa, so we have $|C_a| \le k$ with equality holding for the forbidden trivial case of $a=1$.

Also note that $C_a=C_{1/a}$, as this this just means transposing every pair $(i,j)$ into $(j,i)$. So we can concentrate on looking at $0 < a < 1$ cases, any solution here will have a corresponding solution $\frac1a$.

So let's assume

$$a=\frac{p}q,\, p,q \in \mathbb Z,\, p,q > 0,\, \gcd(p,q)=1,\, p < q$$

wich means we need to find $(i,j)$ such that

$$\frac{p}q=\frac{j}i \Longleftrightarrow pi=qj.$$

Since $q$ and $p$ have no common divisor greater than 1, that means $q|i$, so $i=fq$ for some integer $f \ge 1$. That means $j=\frac{pi}q=p\frac{i}q=fp \in \mathbb Z$. So if $q|i$, we can find a positive (since $f,p > 0$) integer $j=fp$ that makes $\frac{j}i=a$ come true.

In addition, if we assume $i \le k$ we get that $j = \frac{pi}q = i\frac{p}q < i \le k$, as we assumed $a=\frac{p}q < 1$.

So that means we know that for each $(i,j) \in C_a$, with $a=\frac{p}q < 1$ in reduced form, $q|i$ is a necessary condition, but also suffienct, as the corresponding $j=ai$ is an integer in the range $1 \le j \le n$.

That means

$$|C_a|=|\{i\in \mathbb N, 1\le i\le k : q|i \}|$$.

The cardinality if the second set above is easy to calculate, its simply $\lfloor\frac{k}q\rfloor$, which is maximized if $q$ is as low as possible, and for $a=\frac{p}q < 1$ in reduced form that happens when $q=2$, so $a=\frac12$.

It never gets better, though there are a few small $k$ cases where it's not the only optimum. For $k=1$, we get $|C_a|=0$ for all $a \neq 1$. For $k=2$ it's the only optimum. For $k=3$, $q=3$ also works, as $|C_{1/2}|=|C_{1/3}|=|C_{2/3}|=1$. For $k=4,5$ there are 2 even integers in the range $1\ldots k$, but only one divisble by $3$, so again $q=2$ is the only optimal value.

For $k=6$, both counts get upped by $1$ at the same time, so still $q=2$ is the only optimal value. In addition, as $6$ is divisible by both $2$ and $2$, the count for $q=3$ can never reach the count for $q=2$, as the count for $2$ always gets incremented earlier than the correpondig count for $3$.

To get the final answer:

For $k=1$, each $a\neq 1$ is qually bad, producing an empty intersection of $A$ and $B$.

For $k\ge 2$, $a=\frac12, a=2$ produce optimal solutions, with $|A \cap B|=\lfloor\frac{k}2\rfloor$.

Those are the only optimal solutions, except for $k=3$, where $a=\frac13, a=\frac23, a=\frac32, a=3$ also produce an optimal solution of $|A \cap B| =1$.